# phonegap scandit plugin close

Tags: cordova, barcode

I have created a small application using PhoneGap and the Android plugin scandit.
It should work like this: 
The user click on the button that starts the scan,
the app registers the barcode that is saved in localStorage and the camera closes.
The problem is that, after scanning the barcode, the camera will not close! 
To make it close or I have to press the back button many time, or record another barcode!

Someone can help me?

Thank you very much!

This is the code for scan:

```
$('#scanner').on('click', function (e) {
cordova.exec(
function success(resultArray) {
alert("Scanned " + resultArray[0] + " code: " + resultArray[1])
},function failure(error) {
alert("Failed: " + error)},
"ScanditSDK", "scan",
["keykeykeykeykey",
{ "beep": true,"ean13AndUpc12": true,"qr": true,"code39": true,
"ean8": true,"1DScanning" : true,"2DScanning" : true }]);
window.localStorage["barcode"] = resultArray[0];});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that has so far never shown up for us. It would be great if you could tell us what SDK version you are using, what device you are testing it on and what version of Android the device is running.

Please first also test it with our most recent PhoneGap plugin available on GitHub: https://github.com/Scandit/BarcodeScannerPlugin